# React Native: How to set <TextInput/>'s height and width to <View/> container?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I currently have a `<TextInput>` inside a `<View>` that has a `padding: 15`. I would like for the `<TextInput>'s` width and height to cover all space inside `<View>` except the padding.

So I tried `var width = Dimensions.get('window').width` and the following, but the `< TextInput >` abide to the padding on the left but when you continue to type, it goes beyond the right side padding:

```
<View style = {{ padding: 15 }}> <TextInput style = {{ width: width }} /> </View>
```

So how can I get the TextInput to cover all space, height and width, inside View yet abide to the View's padding rule as well?

Thank you

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try setting the styling of TextInput to flex: 1 instead of getting the width. The Flex style will automatically fill your view and leave the padding blank.

```
<View style = {{ padding: 15 }}> <TextInput style = {{ flex: 1 }} /> </View>
```

Comment: thank you! It's working nicely. One question, why does it have to be clicked right at the beginning of the TextInput to get the text cursor up and to start typing? How can I do it so that if I click anywhere the TextInput covers, the text cursor at the beginning will pop up and I can start typing?

Comment: This only handles width but the question is how to set height and width to view container.

Answer (score 19):

Another good answer would be to add:

```
alignItems: 'stretch'
```

alignItems: 'stretch' will stretch every child element along the Cross Axis as long as the child element does not have a specified width (flexDirection: row) or height (flexDirection: column). ​

In your container if you have one, something like:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  }
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it handles height and width, not just width.

Answer (score 1):

try getting the `View`'s dimensions first:

```
<View 
    onLayout={(event) => {
        var {x_pos, y_pos, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    }} 
/>
```

Then use the retrieved width and height to set your `TextInput`'s width and height. The only thing is you get these values on runtime.